# AbstractMethodError when including [org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-client "9.3.6.v20151106"]

Tags: eclipse, clojure, websocket, jetty

I have a clojure web project. Lately I included this dep:

```
[org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-client "9.3.6.v20151106"]
```

into my project and all of a sudden I cannot serve files anymore. There is no stacktrace or anything available. So I attached a debugger and stopped on all exceptions and this is the one I found:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.newEndPoint(Ljava/nio/channels/SocketChannel;
Lorg/eclipse/jetty/io/ManagedSelector;
Ljava/nio/channels/SelectionKey;)Lorg/eclipse/jetty/io/EndPoint;
```

Any ideas what might cause this? Do I need another dependency? to make the websocket-client jar work?

These are all my projects dependencies:

```
[org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-client "9.3.6.v20151106"]
 [org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.189"]

 [ring "1.4.0"]
 [lib-noir "0.9.9"]
 [ring-server "0.4.0"]
 [ring/ring-anti-forgery "1.0.0"]
 [compojure "1.4.0"]
 [reagent "0.5.1"]
 [environ "1.0.1"]
 [leiningen "2.5.1"]
 [http-kit "2.1.19"]
 [selmer "0.9.5"]
 [prone "0.8.2"]
 [im.chit/cronj "1.4.4"]
 [com.taoensso/timbre "3.2.1"]
 [noir-exception "0.2.5"]

 [buddy/buddy-auth "0.8.2"]
 [buddy/buddy-hashers "0.9.1"]

 [log4j "1.2.17" :exclusions [javax.mail/mail
                              javax.jms/jms
                              com.sun.jdmk/jmxtools
                              com.sun.jmx/jmxri]]

 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.4.2"]
 [korma "0.4.2"]
 [com.h2database/h2 "1.4.190"]
 [org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc "3.8.11.2"]

 [com.draines/postal "1.11.4"]

 [jarohen/nomad "0.7.2"]

 [de.sveri/clojure-commons "0.2.0"]

 [clojure-miniprofiler "0.5.0"]

 [org.danielsz/system "0.2.0"]

 [datascript "0.13.3"]
 [cljs-ajax "0.5.2"]
 [ring-transit "0.1.4"]
 [com.lucasbradstreet/cljs-uuid-utils "1.0.2"]

 [net.tanesha.recaptcha4j/recaptcha4j "0.0.8"]

 [com.taoensso/tower "3.0.2"]

 [org.clojure/core.typed "0.3.19"]
 [prismatic/plumbing "0.5.2"]
 [prismatic/schema "1.0.4"]

 [com.rpl/specter "0.9.0"]

 [clj-http "2.0.0"]
 [cheshire "5.5.0"]
 [alandipert/storage-atom "1.2.4"]
 [org.clojure/core.memoize "0.5.8"]

 [org.clojure/core.async "0.2.374"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone on slack told me to look for other dependencies pulling in websocket-client. And indeed, ring-jetty-adapter imports an older version which leads to the Exception. This is the solution:

```
[ring "1.4.0"]
[lib-noir "0.9.9"]
[org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server "9.3.6.v20151106"]
[ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.4.0" :exclusions [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server]]
```